# Problema con tchar.h C++

Tags: c++

tengo un programa de consola que tiene definido valores de tchar pero en otras partes no lo detecta y me tira el error
"E0020  el identificador "L" no está definido"

Cuando mas abajo si esta definido

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCkfd.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztVKH.jpg

```
#include "funcs.h"
#include <tchar.h>
#include <tchar.h>
DWORD WINAPI six()
{

    AllocConsole();
    freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    system("%random%");
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
    COORD scrollbar = {
        csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1,
        csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top + 1
    };
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), scrollbar);
    SetWindowLong(GetConsoleWindow(), GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(GetConsoleWindow(), GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX & ~WS_SIZEBOX);
    
    while (!FindWindow(_T(xor("LWJGL")), nullptr))
    {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 14 | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
        printf(xor("\rWaiting for minecraft process..."));
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));

    }
```

Hay un error de "E0020 el identificador "L" no está definido" en

```
while (!FindWindow(_T(xor("LWJGL")), nullptr))
```

Comment: He leído 6 veces tu pregunta y no la he entendido. ¿Podrías publicar tu código, el error que ves, lo que esperabas ver y reformular tu pregunta?

Comment: si claro, ahi lo pongo

Comment: Quedo a la espera.

Comment: ahi esta amigo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En C++ existen diferentes tipos de literales de texto, por simplificar mencionaré los literales de caracteres estrechos `"Hola mundo!"` y los literales de caracteres anchos `L"Hola mundo!"`.

Si te fijas, la única diferencia entre ambos literales es la presencia del prefijo `L`.

---

Microsoft hace <strike>una chapuza</strike> un truco para poder compilar código usando caracteres anchos o estrechos indistintamente, usa la macro `_T(literal_de_texto)` que dependiendo de si la macro `_UNICODE` está definida se traduce en "*no le hagas nada al `literal_de_texto`*" o en "*pon el prefijo `L` al `literal_de_texto`*". Esto lo llaman ellos "[*soporte unicode*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/text/unicode-programming-summary)".

Como puedes ver la macro `_T` está diseñada para recibir un literal de texto como parámetro, sin embargo tú la has usado sobre una expresión:

```
while (!FindWindow(_T(xor("LWJGL")), nullptr))
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- Expresión
```

Posiblemente querías hacer esto:

```
while (!FindWindow(xor(_T("LWJGL")), nullptr))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!